# Exception: Package android does not belong to 2000

Tags: android, adb

I have my Android device connected to my laptop and When I try to run:

```
adb shell pm set-install-location 2
```

I am getting this error:

```
"Package android does not belong to 2000"
```

What does it means?

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 15):

After "adb devices" just type "adb shell" (enter) then type "su" (enter and accept on the phone display), This enables SuperUser. Now you can type "pm set-install-location 2"
Verify the new destination with "pm get-install-location"

Comment: This was the correct answer, even though Rushang Prajapati's answer mention the correct precaution for such an operation

Comment: It may be worth noting that on Android 5+, you will get the error "su: not found" unless your phone is rooted or you come across some other way to provide a su binary.

Comment: I am trying to find proof of this part of Rushang Prajapati's answer: Any application on the SD card would be able to write to any file on that storage / potentially replace proper apps, whereas on internal phone storage they won't be able to. Can any app on internal phone storage READ any file on there? And can they READ any file on the sdcard anyway? I've made a number of searches and I'm having no luck supporting that theory. I'd really like to know more about that! In my case, my phone seems to have confused part of its internal storage as external (there's no SD), so I want that default.

Answer (score 13):

"Basically speaking: You can't. At least not without rooting.
The main reasons Android does not allow you to install an application to your external SD card are:

Security: It's the main reason for that restriction. Basic file systems like NTFS or FAT (any version of it) do not allow for Unix-like permission management.
This means: any application would be able to write to any file on that storage.
Thinking of malicious apps, they would be able to replace proper apps with fake/infected ones, bricking your phone and rendering it unusable.

Volatile storage: Your external SD card is not safe to be inserted in your device all the time. You are able to eject it any time what makes your SD card not a very good candidate for a permanent storage. Consider apps running off of your SD card and you eject it. Those apps will just crash and all other apps saved on your SD card are gone as well. You can't use them at that time and the data of those app is also affected by reason #1."